# Angular guard children rendering condition

Tags: angular

I have 3 childrens in a parent component, I would like to render them based on these conditions :

- if my variable is equal to zero, render the welcomePage
- else if my variable is between one and ten, render the intermediatePage,
- else, render the dashboard page

I tried this code but it's not working :
`Router :`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: WelcomeComponent,
        canActivateChild: [WelcomeGuard],
        children: [
            { path: '', component: WelcomePageComponent },
            { path: 'intermediate', component: WelcomeIntermediateComponent },
            { path: 'dashboard', component: WelcomeDashboardComponent },
        ],
    },
];
```

`Guard :`

```js
export class WelcomeGuard implements CanActivateChild {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    canActivateChild(
        childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
        const variable = 0;
        if (variable === 0) {
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
            return false;
        } else if (variable >= 1 && variable <= 10) {
            this.router.navigate(['/intermediate']);
            return false;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a few changes to get your code works.

### **Router**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivateChild: [WelcomeGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomePageComponent },
      { path: 'intermediate', component: WelcomeIntermediateComponent },
      { path: 'dashboard', component: WelcomeDashboardComponent },
    ],
  },
];
```

---

### **Guard**

```
export class WelcomeGuard implements CanActivateChild {
  canActivateChild(
    childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
    const variable = 0;
    if (variable === 0) {
      return true;
    } else if (variable >= 1 && variable <= 10) {
      return this.router.parseUrl('/intermediate');
    } else {
      return this.router.parseUrl('/dashboard');
    }
  }
}
```

---